# Positioning absolute element next to another element within a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position a popover in a side menu that is a long menu and is scrollable. I am having difficulties getting the popover to display in the correct location after the user has scrolled the menu.

Here is a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/qz14ear3/) of my problem.

In the side menu there are several sections each with their own button to display a popover, and the popover should be positioned within that section.

I know that this would be easily done if I could simply place the popover within the section HTML itself and just position it to the parent, however I **cannot** restructure the HTML to include the popover within the section itself.

The issue I have is how popovers 5 and 6 do not open in their associated sections.

Here is the code. As you can see the popover works just fine if you have not yet scrolled the side menu, however if you scroll the side menu then open popovers 5 or 6 you will see that they are displayed way too low outside of my menu container:

```js
clearPopovers = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.popover').forEach((p) => p.classList.add('hidden'));
};

var togglePopover = function (popoverId, sectionId) {
  // Removing any existing popovers
  clearPopovers();

  var popoverToToggle = document.getElementById(popoverId);
  var sectionToPlacePopover = document.getElementById(sectionId);

  popoverToToggle.style.top = sectionToPlacePopover.offsetTop + sectionToPlacePopover.scrollTop + 'px';
  popoverToToggle.classList.remove('hidden')
}

$('#container').on('scroll', function() {
  clearPopovers();
});
```

```css
.container { 
  background-color: #FFFFF0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.popover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border:  2px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.hidden { 
  display: none;
}

.section {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popoverOne" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 1
</div>
<div id="popoverTwo" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 2
</div>
<div id="popoverThree" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 3
</div>
<div id="popoverFour" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 4
</div>
<div id="popoverFive" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 5
</div>
<div id="popoverSix" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 6
</div>

<p>
 Look at the JSFiddle as SO's editor is hard to see the issue. Look at Popovers 5 and 6, they are broken because you have to scroll the container. Popovers 1-4 work fine because you do not have to scroll.
</p>

<div  id="container" class="container">
  <div class="section" id="sectionOne">
    1 I'm a side menu<br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverOne', 'sectionOne')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
    
  <div class="section" id="sectionTwo">
    2 With options<br/> 2 and a button to show a popover<br/>2 <br/> 2 <br/> 2 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverTwo', 'sectionTwo')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionThree">
    3 <br/> 3<br/> 3 <br/>3<br/> 3 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverThree', 'sectionThree')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionFour">
    4 <br/> 4<br/> 4 <br/> 4 <br/> 4 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverFour', 'sectionFour')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
   
  <div class="section" id="sectionFive">
    5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverFive', 'sectionFive')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionSix">
    6 <br/> 6 <br/> 6<br/> 6 <br/>6<br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverSix', 'sectionSix')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried dozens of variations of trying to take the `offsetParent.offsetTop`, the `body`'s `scrollY`, and the `offsetTop` but I cannot get any combination of things to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/qz14ear3/71/).

The code was really close, you simply need to take the popovers `sectionToPlacePopover`'s `offsetTop` **minus** the side menu `container`'s `scroll position like this:

`popoverToToggle.style.top = sectionToPlacePopover.offsetTop - containerScrollPosition + 'px';`

Which will put the popover at the right distance on the page to match the section it was opened in.

Here is the working code:

```js
clearPopovers = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.popover').forEach((p) => p.classList.add('hidden'));
};

var togglePopover = function (popoverId, sectionId) {
  // Removing any existing popovers
  clearPopovers();

  var popoverToToggle = document.getElementById(popoverId);
  var sectionToPlacePopover = document.getElementById(sectionId);
  var containerScrollPosition = document.getElementById('container').scrollTop;

  popoverToToggle.style.top = sectionToPlacePopover.offsetTop - containerScrollPosition + 'px';
  popoverToToggle.classList.remove('hidden')
};

$('#container').on('scroll', function() {
  clearPopovers();
});
```

```css
.container { 
  background-color: #FFFFF0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.popover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border:  2px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.hidden { 
  display: none;
}

.section {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popoverOne" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 1
</div>
<div id="popoverTwo" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 2
</div>
<div id="popoverThree" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 3
</div>
<div id="popoverFour" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 4
</div>
<div id="popoverFive" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 5
</div>
<div id="popoverSix" class="popover hidden">
 I'm popover 6
</div>

<p>
  Look at Popovers 5 and 6, they are broken because you have to scroll the container. Popovers 1-4 work fine because you do not have to scroll.
</p>

<div  id="container" class="container">
  <div class="section" id="sectionOne">
    1 I'm a side menu<br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/> 1 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverOne', 'sectionOne')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
    
  <div class="section" id="sectionTwo">
    2 With options<br/> 2 and a button to show a popover<br/>2 <br/> 2 <br/> 2 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverTwo', 'sectionTwo')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionThree">
    3 <br/> 3<br/> 3 <br/>3<br/> 3 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverThree', 'sectionThree')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionFour">
    4 <br/> 4<br/> 4 <br/> 4 <br/> 4 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverFour', 'sectionFour')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
   
  <div class="section" id="sectionFive">
    5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/> 5 <br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverFive', 'sectionFive')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="sectionSix">
    6 <br/> 6 <br/> 6<br/> 6 <br/>6<br/>
    <button onClick="togglePopover('popoverSix', 'sectionSix')">Show popover for this section</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I named everything with Twiggeh because I wrote the solution alongside what you currently have.

[Your JS Fiddle with my code added](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/fxyatmLk/59/)

#### Javascript

You can change your function to :

```js
const setTwiggehPop = (event) => {

  if (event === undefined) return
  // Correct Target ?
  if (!Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.TwiggehTarget')).includes(event.target)) return

  const coords = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  const overlay = document.getElementById("TwiggehPop");
  overlay.style.display = "block";
  overlay.style.position = "absolute"
  overlay.style.left = coords.x + "px";
  overlay.style.top = window.scrollY + coords.y + "px";

}

window.addEventListener('click', setTwiggehPop)
```

#### Html

and then you only need one popover in html :

```html
<div id="TwiggehPop" style="display:none;">
  I am Twiggeh's popover!
</div>
```

and a simple button that you can copy-paste :

```html
<button class="TwiggehTarget">
  TwiggehPop
</button>
```

#### Other

If you need more than one popup you can get the amount of buttons with `document.querySelectorAll('.TwiggehTarget')` and pool as many popups as you need concurrently.

If you need custom data in the popup you can access any property on the parent / child elements of the target button.